# How to optimize non-negative constraints with gradient descent

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, convex-optimization

I have an optimization in the following form,

argmin_W f(W)
s.t. W_i > 0,  for all i

where W is a vector, and f(W) is a function on W.
I know how to optimize without the non-negative constraints. But I am unsure about how to optimize this with gradient descent.

Answer (score 2):

Optimization on the open set is quite tricky, so let us assume that `W_i >= 0`, consequently you can use many methods:

- optimize f(|W|) on the whole domain
- use GD for f(W) but after each iteration project your solution back to the domain, so put W = |W|
- use constrained optimization techniques, such as L-BFGS-B

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a general and simple way of doing it. You will have to do some sort of search at each point to make sure the constraints are met (techniques like [line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search), [trust regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_region)).

Or perhaps f has some structure you can exploit.